# Post an array to a PHP page from .js file

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, post

I'm trying to pass an array from .js file to a PHP page using ajax post method. would you help me to understand why it is not working?

```
//js file
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "http://localhost/Project_part3/includes/graph.php",
       datatype: 'JSON',
       data: {'data1' : JSON.stringify(data1)},
       success: function(data){
        console.log("success:", data1);
    },
       failure: function(errMsg) {
        console.error("error:",errMsg);
       }
    });

//PHP page
<?php
  $data1 = json_encode($_POST["data1"]);
  var_dump ($_POST["data1"]);
?>
```

Comment: How do you know it is not working? Have you watched the request/response in the browser's developer tools? Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Shouldn't the PHP json_decode to turn the string into an array?

Comment: @NasimKhaloo, Harvey has right you are sending an string not an array check his answer

Comment: check console.log("success:", data); <== not data1 to see the var_dump

Answer (score 1):

If your `data1` array in your JS is already a javascript array, you don't need to do `JSON.stringify()` as this is making it into a string.

You will now be able to just do `data: data1`

```
var data1 = {
        yourKey1: "yourValue",
        yourKey2: "moreStuff"
    };

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "http://localhost/Project_part3/includes/graph.php",
   datatype: 'JSON',
   data: data1,
   success: function(data){
    console.log("success:", data1);
},
   failure: function(errMsg) {
    console.error("error:",errMsg);
   }
});
```